# Javafx 8 using KeyEvents with ImageView

Tags: event-handling, imageview, javafx-8, keyevent, 2d-games

I am trying to make a game on Javafx 8 using NetBeans 8.1. The super class of all my game objects is ImageView and I would like to handle key events within a game object instead of in my Scene. The problem is that KeyEvents seem to only work on the Scene and when I add a KeyEvent Handler to my game object nothing happens when I press the keys. Is there anyway to add KeyEvents to any Node, such as an ImageView, and have it work? Below is an example of what I am aiming for (VisibleGameObject extends ImageView):

```
package hangmanElements;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafxgame2D.gameObjects.VisibleGameObject;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;


public class HangmanPost extends VisibleGameObject
{
    public HangmanPost()
    {
        super(new Image("/resources/hangmanPost.png"));
        setOriginAtCenter();
        setPosition(100, 250);
        setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) 
        {
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP)
            {
                System.out.println("Up pressed MAN!");
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void update() 
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key events are only generated by scene graph nodes when they have keyboard focus. By default, an `ImageView` does not gain keyboard focus. You need to call

```
setFocusTraversable(true);
```

on the `ImageView`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have another question on top of that, can multiple ImageViews and Nodes similar to it gain keyboard focus?

Comment: UPDATE: I just tried it out, and it seems that only one Node can have keyboard focus, and you have to press Tab to switch focus, the same way you press Tab to move between text fields on a webpage. Is it possible to just check if a keyboard button has been pressed from anywhere in the code, for example:

if(keyboard.isPressed(KeyCode.A){...} ?

Comment: To do that you would just do as you originally did, and register the listener with the Scene.